# C programming. Can i display value in file

Tags: c, file-io, data-structures

```
    case '2' :
        {
            FILE *fp = fopen("C:/project/Value.txt","r");
            printf("\t\t\t\tDELETE\n");
            printf("\t-------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("\t\tVALUE IS ");
            int i=0;
            while(feof(fp))
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%d",&value[i]);
                printf("%d ",value[i]);
                i++;
            }
            fclose(fp);
            break;
        }
```

**I have Probelm in Case 2. i have Value in file but not Display a Value**

Comment: Never use `feof` *before* any reading operation. Use it just after a read.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's interesting that you say that. But see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xssktc6e.aspx), where feof is used in exactly the way you're warning against. Can you justify why that is?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose `Value.txt` has some integers in it. You can change you loop to the following to make it work:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&value[i])==1) //while fscanf is successful
    printf("%d ",value[i++]); //print and then increment i
```

Read [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) to know why `while(!feof())` is wrong(You missed the `!` before `feof()`)

Comment: This is incorrect, since fscanf can return EOF, while loop will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You used while(feof(fp)).Initially fp is pointing to first charector in file but not EOF character so feof returns 0 and the loop gets stopped without being entered into it.So to eradicate this use while(!feof(fp)) in your code if you are shure that there are values related to a single datatype that you are using.for example as in your code only integers or characters etc.

```
          while(!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d",&value[i]);
            printf("%d ",value[i]);
            i++;
        }
```

But if you have multiple datatypes and you want only first integers to be printed use

```
      while((!feof(fp))&&(fscanf(fp,"%d",&value[i])))
      {
         printf("%d ",value[i]);
         i++;

      }
```

in this case fscanf returns 0 when Eof is reached .

Comment: This is incorrect, since fscanf can return EOF, while loop will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Of course it can. It says so in the documentation and in the Standard. You can look it up.

Comment: you are right now i have edited it and the code looks fine

Comment: The comparison is still incorrect. feof() returns a non-zero if EOF is set. And the order of both call in the if statement should be reversed or you will print an additional bogus value.

Comment: Check it now how it works

Comment: This goes fine and works well